# Iterating over data and mapping to different component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to float a set of components left and right in an alternating fashion. I can not seem to find a way to make it work using props.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
const Calendar = ({events}) => (
  <div>
    <Title/>
    <div className="events">
      {events.events.map(event =>
      <EventCard key={Math.random()} event={event} align="left"/>,
      <EventCard key={Math.random()} event={event} align="right"/>
      )}
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

However I receive only components with the `align="left"` prop. Can you tell me how to alternate this mapping?

Comment: Remove the comma and wrap `EventCard's` into braces `(...)`.

Comment: @KonradD That won't make much of a desirable difference? That'll just return the latter of two?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to wrap both of them in a parent element. The reason you're only getting one is because of the comma, which is interpreted as another argument being passed to `map`. For example:

```
{
  events.events.map(event =>
    <div>
      <EventCard key={Math.random()} event={event} align="left"/>
      <EventCard key={Math.random()} event={event} align="right"/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

And I would highly suggest something other than using random numbers as keys because that's an antipattern. React needs some kind of predictable number for keys that are guaranteed to be unique, which random numbers are not.

If you don't like the extra element, and if you're using React 16, you can use their new feature of return an array of children instead of having a parent:

```
{
  events.events.map(event =>
    [
      <EventCard key={Math.random()} event={event} align="left"/>,
      <EventCard key={Math.random()} event={event} align="right"/>
    ]
  )
}
```

Again, I would highly recommend using something other than `Math.random` such as giving each event a specific ID.

Comment: Thank you! this worked! However I was going about it the wrong way as this returns two EventCards with the same event data. I need to map over two different but sequential event indexes in an array. I just can not seem to do this with a map function.

Comment: Oh. That's what I suspected too. You could try alternating by index, checking if it's even or odd to alternate them: `events.events.map((event, index) => index % 2 != 0 ? leftonehere : rightonehere)`. This will essentially check if the index is odd. If it is odd, then the left event will show, and if it's even, then the right one will show.